# rolling function using previous row values [R]

Tags: r, datatable, zoo

I have some sites (`a,b,c`) where the soil has a certain maximum capacity (`100,200`). For each period of time (every row in my dataset), I have calculated the change in water content (`change`).

```
set.seed(2023)
db <- data.table(ID=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3)),
                 capacity=c(rep(100,3),rep(200,6)),
                 prc=round(runif(9,1,100),0),
                 evpt=round(runif(9,1,100),0))

db[prc>=evpt,change:=prc-evpt]
db[prc<evpt,change:=exp(-((evpt-prc)/capacity))]


   ID capacity prc evpt     change
1:  a      100  39   20 19.0000000
2:  a      100  74   35 39.0000000
3:  a      100  67   19 48.0000000
4:  b      200  49   78  0.8650223
5:  b      200  41   70  0.8650223
6:  b      200  94   75 19.0000000
7:  c      200  74   51 23.0000000
8:  c      200  67   71  0.9801987
9:  c      200  77   73  4.0000000
```

At time 0 the site hold the maximum `capacity` of water. Then, if `prc` >`evpt`, `change` is the water added to the previous content, without exceeding the maximum capacity. If `prc` < `evpt`, `change` is a multiplier of the previous water content, thus reducing the content.

```
# draft function
new_content <- function(change,capacity,prc,evpt){
  if (prc>evpt) {
    min(change+previous_content,capacity)
    } else {
      previous_content*change
    }
}
```

Then I should apply the function for each site to get a new column (`content`) showing the temporal variation of water content. As in the following output calculated in Excel:

```
> db
   ID capacity prc evpt     change  content
1:  a      100  39   20 19.0000000 100.0000
2:  a      100  74   35 39.0000000 100.0000
3:  a      100  67   19 48.0000000 100.0000
4:  b      200  49   78  0.8650223 173.0045
5:  b      200  41   70  0.8650223 149.6527
6:  b      200  94   75 19.0000000 168.6527
7:  c      200  74   51 23.0000000 200.0000
8:  c      200  67   71  0.9801987 196.0397
9:  c      200  77   73  4.0000000 200.0000
```

The problem I cannot solve is how to define the variable `previous_content`, i.e. at the beginning equal to the maximum capacity and then to the content of the previous row.

I checked the documentation of both `data.table::frollapply` and `zoo:rollapply` but I was not able even to write a starting draft for that. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Could you please show what the desired outcome (i.e., the final data.table) should look like based on the input data `db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input shown in the Note at the end `content2` generated using `Reduce` is the same as `content`:

```
db[, content2 := Reduce(function(x, i) with(.SD[i, ], {
    if (prc > evpt) min(change+x, capacity)
    else x * change
  }), 1:.N, init = capacity[1], acc = TRUE)[-1], by = ID]

db
##    ID capacity prc evpt     change  content content2
## 1:  a      100  39   20 19.0000000 100.0000 100.0000
## 2:  a      100  74   35 39.0000000 100.0000 100.0000
## 3:  a      100  67   19 48.0000000 100.0000 100.0000
## 4:  b      200  49   78  0.8650223 173.0045 173.0045
## 5:  b      200  41   70  0.8650223 149.6527 149.6527
## 6:  b      200  94   75 19.0000000 168.6527 168.6527
## 7:  c      200  74   51 23.0000000 200.0000 200.0000
## 8:  c      200  67   71  0.9801987 196.0397 196.0397
## 9:  c      200  77   73  4.0000000 200.0000 200.0000
```

In the example in the question `capacity` is always constant within `ID` and `change` is multiplied if it is <= 1 and added otherwise.  If those are true generally we can simplify the above:

```
db[, content3 := Reduce(function(x, change) 
      if (change > 1) min(change + x, capacity[1]) else x * change, 
      change, init = capacity[1], acc = TRUE)[-1], 
    by = ID]
```

### Note

```
library(data.table)

Lines <-  "ID capacity prc evpt     change  content
a      100  39   20 19.0000000 100.0000
a      100  74   35 39.0000000 100.0000
a      100  67   19 48.0000000 100.0000
b      200  49   78  0.8650223 173.0045
b      200  41   70  0.8650223 149.6527
b      200  94   75 19.0000000 168.6527
c      200  74   51 23.0000000 200.0000
c      200  67   71  0.9801987 196.0397
c      200  77   73  4.0000000 200.0000"
db <- fread(Lines)
```

Comment: Yes your assumptions were correct, as well as the starting data you used. I managed to make a mistake while making the first part of the reproducible example.